# Jaxrs - how to read xml?

Tags: java, xml, jax-rs

I create rest api with jax-rs. I want handle PUT request with xml. I create method:

```
   @PUT
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   @Path("/createOrder")
   @Override
   public void createOrder(String content)
   {
      ///some code
   }
```

Send data by PUT

```
Address: http://some_address/web-services/rest/createOrder
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: PUT
Content-Type: aplication/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate,sdch], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.8], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[117], content-type=[aplication/xml], cookie=[JSESSIONID=CE083800388A447F94FBB1E75E994EA9], host=[localhost:8080], origin=[chrome-extension://fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36]}
Payload: <note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

and get this error:

```
WARNING: No operation matching request path "/web-services/rest/createOrder" is found, Relative Path: /createOrder, HTTP Method: PUT, ContentType: aplication/xml, Accept: */*,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
```

All GET methods work but I can't handle PUT. How to do it?

Comment: application/xml has two p's (in your Content-Type header)

Answer (score 0):

The request header 'Content-Type' is wrong. It says a`p`lication/xml instead of a`pp`lication/xml.

Also I've never seen `Payload` as a header. The xml content should be in the body part of the request.

Comment: I use chrome plugin POSTMAN to test and it sents Pyalod as header. As @nablex said it's two p's problem. When I change header to application/xml it works. I changed metdoh signature to public void createOrder(XMLSource source) and stream has content of xml that I sent.